# How to setup CruiseControl.net with git in a windows server

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net, openssh, windows-server, ccnet-config

Can anyone help me to setup Cruisecontrol.net with git repository.

This is what I include in the cruisecontrol config file

```
<project name="MyFirstProject"
           description="demoproject showing a small config">
<sourcecontrol type="git">
  <repository>git@test.unfuddle.com:test/testplayground.git</repository>
  <branch>master</branch>
  <autoGetSource>true</autoGetSource>

  <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe</executable>
  <tagOnSuccess>false</tagOnSuccess>


  <tagCommitMessage>CCNet Build {0}</tagCommitMessage>
 <committerName>CCNET</committerName>
  <committerEMail>tranjan@gmail.com</committerEMail>
  <tagNameFormat>CCNet-Build-{0}</tagNameFormat>

  <workingDirectory>c:\TestCCNET\</workingDirectory>
  <timeout>600000</timeout>
</sourcecontrol>
```

[image]

But when I run the ccnet console it fails.

I used openSSH keys(private and public).

I think it is something wrong with authentication.

When I use git bash to clone the repository it is working. But fails with CCNET

I spent more than 2 days to setup my build server. still can't get it right.

I need some assistance/guidance.

Is there a proper article or blog that describe correct steps ?

I search all over the internet and tried lots of things. Didnt work :(

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

you'll find all information on our [Git Wiki Page](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Git) in the "Notes" section.

1. Use git.cmd and not git.exe
2. CCNet runs as a service, right? Log-in as the user the service runs on and test if authentication works, if not set it up. (Best practise is to create a user the ccnet service runs on)
3. Please paste the complete log of this integration run in debug/trace mode, the 3-liner is not helpful.

Comment: git.cmd no longer exists in msysgit. Should we be using git-cmd.exe now?